# Parsing XML, need to get element text from a child node which is not always present

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

Fairly new to Python.  I'm parsing XML element text to ultimately be passed to a database but am printing to screen to QA my script.  The following (edited to reduce sample length) gives me exactly what I'm looking for.  My question is: how do I bring in the FreeRents node values without eliminating records which have BaseRents nodes but not FreeRents?  I've tried a for loop but this clearly eliminates records which do not have both BaseRent and FreeRent:

XML:

```
      <Lease>
        <Id>5507160</Id>
        <LeaseType>direct</LeaseType>
        <LeaseExpirationDate>2018-12-31</LeaseExpirationDate>
        <LeaseCommencementDate>1996-12-01</LeaseCommencementDate>
        <ExecutionDate/>
        <LeaseTerm/>
        <LeaseStructure>triple net</LeaseStructure>
        <SourceID>4258_1300</SourceID>
        <Industry/>
        <RenewalStatus>unknown</RenewalStatus>
        <CreatedAt>2018-01-10T20:43:55Z</CreatedAt>
        <UpdatedAt>2018-04-10T16:31:22Z</UpdatedAt>
        <Rights/>
        <LeaseDealTerms>
          <LeaseDealTerm>
            <RentableArea>10740</RentableArea>
            <SecurityDeposit/>
            <NEROverride/>
            <MiscDescription>Miscellaneous Description</MiscDescription>
            <SourceID>1228_1300</SourceID>
            <IsMonthToMonth>false</IsMonthToMonth>
            <MoveOutDate/>
            <BaseRents>
              <BaseRent>
                <StartDate>2018-01-01</StartDate>
                <EndDate>2018-01-31</EndDate>
                <Amount>16.0</Amount>
                <Units>rsf/year</Units>
              </BaseRent>
              <BaseRent>
                <StartDate>2018-12-01</StartDate>
                <EndDate>2018-12-31</EndDate>
                <Amount>16.0</Amount>
                <Units>rsf/year</Units>
              </BaseRent>
            </BaseRents>
            <FreeRents>
              <FreeRent>
                <StartDate>2018-05-01</StartDate>
                <EndDate>2018-05-31</EndDate>
                <Amount>5.0</Amount>
                <Units>rsf/year</Units>
                <FreeRentType>net</FreeRentType>
                <Percentage>100.0</Percentage>
              </FreeRent>
              <FreeRent>
                <StartDate>2019-04-01</StartDate>
                <EndDate>2019-04-30</EndDate>
                <Amount>3.0</Amount>
                <Units>rsf/year</Units>
                <FreeRentType>net</FreeRentType>
                <Percentage>100.0</Percentage>
              </FreeRent>
            </FreeRents>
          </LeaseDealTerm>
        </LeaseDealTerms>
        <Tenant>
          <Id>993183</Id>
          <CompanyName>Sample Company LTD.</CompanyName>
        </Tenant>
      </Lease>
```

Script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pyodbc

server = "servername, port"
database = "DestDB"
username = "foo"
password = "bar"


con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};\
SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+";UID="+username+";PWD="+password+";Trusted_Connection=yes;")
x = con.cursor()

tree = ET.parse(r'\\server\FileName.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for ls in root.findall("PortfolioData/Properties/Property/Spaces/Space/Lease"):
    lsid = ls.find("Id").text
    for ldt in ls.findall("LeaseDealTerms/LeaseDealTerm"):
        ldra = ldt.find("RentableArea").text
        try:
            unitnum = ldt.find("SourceID").text.split("_")[1]
        except:
            unitnum = None
        secdep = ldt.find("SecurityDeposit").text
        nero = ldt.find("NEROverride").text
        lsdesc = ldt.find("MiscDescription").text #Jeff asked for this
        mtm = ldt.find("IsMonthToMonth").text
        moutdt = ldt.find("MoveOutDate").text
        for br in ldt.findall("BaseRents/BaseRent"):
            brstdt = br.find("StartDate").text
            brenddt = br.find("EndDate").text
            bramt = br.find("Amount").text
            brunit = br.find("Units").text

            if lsid == "5507160": 
                print(lsid, unitnum, ldra, secdep, nero, lsdesc, mtm, moutdt, brenddt, bramt, brunit)
```

Result (without FreeRents):

```
5507160 1300 10740 None None Miscellaneous Description false 2018-01-01 2018-01-31 16.0 rsf/year
5507160 1300 10740 None None Miscellaneous Description false 2018-12-01 2018-12-31 16.0 rsf/year
```

Desired Result:

```
5507160 1300 10740 None None Miscellaneous Description false 2018-01-01 2018-01-31 16.0 rsf/year 2018-05-01 2018-05-31 5.0 rsf/year net 100.0
5507160 1300 10740 None None Miscellaneous Description false 2018-12-01 2018-12-31 16.0 rsf/year 2019-04-01 2018-04-30 3.0 rsf/year net 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized that my for loops were incorrectly written - I'd tried to nest too deeply resulting in incomplete results.  The corrected script references:

for br in ldt.findall("BaseRents"):

instead of:

for br in ldt.findall("BaseRents/BaseRent"):

Similar structure for FreeRents returned a complete result set.  Complete updated script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pyodbc

server = "servername, port"
database = "DestDB"
username = "foo"
password = "bar"

con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};\
SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+";UID="+username+";PWD="+password+";Trusted_Connection=yes;")
x = con.cursor()

tree = ET.parse(r'\\server\FileName.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for ls in root.findall("PortfolioData/Properties/Property/Spaces/Space/Lease"):
lsid = ls.find("Id").text
for ldt in ls.findall("LeaseDealTerms/LeaseDealTerm"):
    ldra = ldt.find("RentableArea").text
    try:
        unitnum = ldt.find("SourceID").text.split("_")[1]
    except:
        unitnum = None
    secdep = ldt.find("SecurityDeposit").text
    nero = ldt.find("NEROverride").text
    lsdesc = ldt.find("MiscDescription").text #Jeff asked for this
    mtm = ldt.find("IsMonthToMonth").text
    moutdt = ldt.find("MoveOutDate").text
    try:
        retasgw = ldt.find("Retail/AnnualSalesGrowthRate").text
    except:
        retasgw = None
    try:
        retpct = ldt.find("Retail/PercentRate").text
    except:
        retpct = None
    try:
        retesale = ldt.find("Retail/UnnaturalBreakpoint").text
    except:
        retesale = None

    for br in ldt.findall("BaseRents"):
        try:
            brstdt = br.find("BaseRent/StartDate").text
        except:
            brstdt = None
        try:
            brenddt = br.find("BaseRent/EndDate").text
        except:
            brenddt = None
        try:
            bramt = br.find("BaseRent/Amount").text
        except:
            bramt = None
        try:
            brunit = br.find("BaseRent/Units").text
        except:
            brunit = None

    for br in ldt.findall("FreeRents"):
        try:
            frstdt = br.find("FreeRent/StartDate").text
        except:
            frstdt = None
        try:
            frenddt = br.find("FreeRent/EndDate").text
        except:
            frenddt = None
        try:
            framt = br.find("FreeRent/Amount").text
        except:
            framt = None
        try:
            frunit = br.find("FreeRent/Units").text
        except:
            frunit = None
        try:
            frtype = br.find("FreeRent/FreeRentType").text
        except:
            frtype = None
        try:
            frpct = br.find("FreeRent/Percentage").text
        except:
            frpct = None
    for opex in ldt.findall("OpExs"):
        try:
            opstdt = opex.find("OpEx/StartDate").text
        except:
            opstdt = None
        try:
            openddt = opex.find("OpEx/EndDate").text
        except:
            openddt = None
        try:
            opamt = opex.find("OpEx/Amount").text
        except:
            opamt = None
        try:
            opunits = opex.find("OpEx/Units").text
        except:
            opunits = None
    for rtax in ldt.findall("RealEstateTaxes"):
        try:
            rtstdt = rtax.find("RealEstateTax/StartDate").text
        except:
            rtstdt = None
        try:
            rtenddt = rtax.find("RealEstateTax/EndDate").text
        except:
            rtenddt = None
        try:
            rtamt = rtax.find("RealEstateTax/Amount").text
        except:
            rtamt = None
        try:
            rtunits = rtax.find("RealEstateTax/Units").text
        except:
            rtunits = None
    for orev in ldt.findall("OtherRevenues"):
        try:
            orstdt = orev.find("OtherRevenues/StartDate").text
        except:
            orstdt = None
        try:
            orenddt = orev.find("OtherRevenues/EndDate").text
        except:
            orenddt = None
        try:
            oramt = orev.find("OtherRevenues/Amount").text
        except:
            oramt = None
        try:
            orunits = orev.find("OtherRevenues/Units").text
        except:
            orunits = None
        try:
            ortype = orev.find("OtherRevenues/Type").text
        except:
            ortype = None

if lsid is not None:
    x.execute("Insert into portfoliodealterms (lsid, unitnum, ldra, secdep, nero, lsdesc, mtm, moutdt, retasgw, \
         retpct, retesale, brstdt, brenddt, bramt, brunit, frstdt, frenddt, framt, frunit, frtype, frpct, opstdt, \
         openddt, opamt, opunits, rtstdt, rtenddt, rtamt, rtunits, orstdt, orenddt, oramt, orunits, ortype) \
        values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, \
        ?, ?, ?)",
        (lsid, unitnum, ldra, secdep, nero, lsdesc, mtm, moutdt, retasgw,
         retpct, retesale, brstdt, brenddt, bramt, brunit, frstdt, frenddt, framt, frunit, frtype, frpct, opstdt,
         openddt, opamt, opunits, rtstdt, rtenddt, rtamt, rtunits, orstdt, orenddt, oramt, orunits, ortype))
    con.commit()
```